# Android slpit string doubleparse and pass it to a method that converts degrres to decimal

Tags: android

I have a android method that converts degrees minutes and seconds to decimal. I am getting the text from edittext split it and convert it to double array before I pass it to the method. Then I wanted to get the double returned in a decimal form to be displayed in the original edittext as string. Here is the code,

```
public double DegreeToDecimal(double d, double m, double s)
    {
        double decimal;
        decimal = d + m/60 + s/3600;

        return decimal;
    }


try
            {
            String string = dtod.getText().toString();
            String[] s = string.split(":");
            String decimal;
            double d = DegreeToDecimal(Double.parseDouble(s[0]), Double.parseDouble(s[1]), Double.parseDouble(s[2]));
            decimal = String.valueOf(d);
            dtod.setText(decimal);
            }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();    

            }
```

When I do this on a button click, nothing happens. The Logcat doesn't show anything and the code is simply ignored. What am I doing wrong? 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: what are you getting in **String[] s** ? are you getting any error/exception ?? Please debug and check

Comment: I am saving the original text in an array so I can split the degrees minutes and seconds and pass them to my method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code formatting is all over the place and hard to read, please try to use correct indentation next time!

From the code you posted it's hard to tell what happens. If Logcat doesn't show any stacktraces like you said, and if your code is "ignored" as you say then my guess is that it doesn't get called.
Did you attach an OnClickListener to that button?

Otherwise try to log something between your lines or use a debugger to find out what really happens!

Comment: thanks for your reply. It's silly mistake, I forgot to set onclicklistener. Now it works fine after I did. I am surprised that it didn't give me stacktrace feedback. This is my first ever question so I didn't know how the indentation stuff works. I appreciate your help :)

Comment: When code doesn't execute then it also cannot produce a stacktrace ;)
Would you mind marking my answer as the accepted answer then? I need the reputation to be able to vote and comment on other threads...